# Rotate a MKMapView while keeping pins in the initial orientation?

Tags: iphone, ios, orientation, mapkit, quartz-graphics

I have an app which runs in portrait mode on iPhone. One of the views in my app is a map. The area which I want to show looks much better in landscape orientation. So, I used The Quartz framework to rotate the map. The problem is, my pins are all sideways now. I'd like to know if I can tell MapKit to rotate the map, while keeping the pins oriented the correct way. Can I do this? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is off the top of my head and thus untested in code.  I also assume that you're not returning custom annotation views for your annotations already.  Consequently, I wonder if you can:

1. Set the delegate for your map view to your view controller.
2. Implement in your view controller: - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id )annotation
3. Return a simple MKPinAnnotationView to which you apply the same transform as you apply to your MKMapView.

Sounds plausible on paper, I think?!

Comment: Perhaps, the only thing is that the transform needs to be done around the same rotation point. I'll test it later and get back to you.

Comment: I've tried it. It just about works, but there are several issues. First of all, the user's location annotation is not properly rotated. Additionally, the map seems to auto-scroll, to show the callout. The problem is that it sometimes does so incorrectly.

Comment: Ok, this is pretty much the closest I'm going to get, so this is correct. A few notes:

1. The height and the width of the frame need to be swapped before the rotation is applied. 

2. The User's Location pin is not simple to rotate. It needs a separate delegate callback to do so.